# Select selected option by class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 select boxes where first is all user selectable but in second selected option is dependant on first select box. Selected value in first option box matches option's class in second select box but values are different. I imagine i need something like:

```
$('#territory').change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == 'EU')
        {
            $('#territory2').class('EU');
        }
```

How do i select selected option by class name? (There might be more than 1 option with the same class name but it just needs to select any of them).

```
     <select id="territory" name="territory"">
        <option value="EU">A</option>
        <option value="GB">B</option>
        <option value="ALL">C</option>
    </select>

    <select id="territory2" name="territory2">
        <option value="1" class="EU">A</option>
        <option value="2" class="GB">B</option>
        <option value="3" class="ALL">C</option>
        <option value="4" class="ALL">D</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Select the option from the second dropdown using the class `(document.querySelector)` and then get its value

Comment: `class` isn't a method.  `addClass`, `removeClass`, or `toggleClass` are

Comment: How do you select an element by its class name? Same thing here, then just set its `selected` property (*not attribute*) to true.

Comment: you've typo problem `<select id="territory" name="territory"">` with the quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `value` attribute of the desired `<option>` element on the `value` attribute of the `<select>`:

```js
const territory = document.getElementById("territory"),
      territory2 = document.getElementById("territory2");

territory.addEventListener("input", ev => {
  territory2.querySelector("."+territory.value).selected = true;
});
```

```html
<select id="territory" name="territory">
    <option value="EU">A</option>
    <option value="GB">B</option>
    <option value="ALL">C</option>
</select>

<select id="territory2" name="territory2">
    <option value="1" class="EU">A</option>
    <option value="2" class="GB">B</option>
    <option value="3" class="ALL">C</option>
    <option value="4" class="ALL">D</option>
</select>
```

Note that this will *only* select the first option with that class.

Comment: Setting the property is more appropriate.  `("GB")[0].selected = true;`

Comment: `select.querySelector('GB').selected = true` would be marginally preferable; it means you don't need to use the index (`[0]`) to choose the first of the matching elements, and using the property is - as Taplar already noted - more appropriate.

Comment: @Taplar That was my first though, but that would require setting all the others to false.

Comment: @D.Pardal in a single-select `select` box, only one can be `selected` at any time, setting one to `true` will automatically set the others to `false` without need to clear existing `selected` values: https://jsfiddle.net/7045hyfg/

Comment: Current solution has error though when running snippet. Previous one with getElementsbyclassname worked @D.Pardal

Comment: @freedomn-m That didn't happen to me, probably because I used `.setAttribute()`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend data-attribute:

```js
$('#territory').on("change", function() {
  const territory = $("option:selected", this).data("territory");
  $("#territory2").val(territory)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="territory" name="territory">
  <option value="" data-territory="0">Please select</option>
  <option value="EU" data-territory="1">A</option>
  <option value="GB" data-territory="2">B</option>
  <option value="ALL" data-territory="3">C</option>
</select>

<select id="territory2" name="territory2">
  <option value="0">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```